# What does $\int e^{jwt}dt$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was looking at the equation $e^{jwt}$ and visualizing it as a cylinder along the x-axis and yz is the complex plane. If we try to write this as a vector-valued function where:

$x$ = $t$, $z$ = $cos(wt)$, $y$ = $sin(wt)$

where $w$ = $2\pi f_{0}$. Then the picture will look like this:

[image]

source: [Understanding DSP frequency domain](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261779218_Understanding_Digital_Signal_Processing%27s_Frequency_Domain)

Now if I intrigate $\int e^{jwt}dt$ = $\int e^{jwx}dx$ what does it mean? Am I finding the area of the cylinder along $x$-axis?

Comment: The integral has a real and an imaginary component, corresponding to integrating over the two (orthogonal) projections.

Comment: Does it mean I am finding the area of those two orthogonal projections?

Comment: Yes... of each one individually.  To see this, write $e^{j \omega t} = \cos (\omega t) + j \sin (\omega t)$ and break the integral into two.